# send token to server Swift 3

Tags: ios, iphone, json, swift

i'm trying to send a token to my server to check if token is still valid or has expired. the token value is pulled from saved data on the device. But no matter what i try it keeps giving me "missing token" which is the status message for when i've sent empty string.

```
    // load content in user var
    user = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "parseJSON") as? NSDictionary

    // if user is once logged in / register, keep him logged in
    if user != nil {
        print(user as Any)

        let userToken = user!["token"] as? String

        let url = NSURL(string: "http://fmm.dummy.com/api/v1/auth/me")!

        var request = URLRequest(url: url as URL)

        request.setValue("Bearer \(String(describing: userToken))", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

        request.httpMethod = "POST"
```

When i edited and did this, the error message change to "invalid token" which meant i was sending something. it just wasn't correct

```
    // load content in user var
    user = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "parseJSON") as? NSDictionary

    // if user is once logged in / register, keep him logged in
    if user != nil {
        print(user as Any)

        let userToken = user!["token"] as? String

        let a: Character = "<"
        let b: Character = ">"
        let url = NSURL(string: "http://fmm.dummy.com/api/v1/auth/me")!

        var request = URLRequest(url: url as URL)

        request.setValue("Bearer .append\(a)\(String(describing: userToken)).append\(b)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

        request.httpMethod = "POST"


        //launch session
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
```

can someone please help me figure out what am doing wrong?
thanks

///EDIT 
Hi when i edited as you had suggested and came up with this, i couldn't even print to console. Here is the full code for your consideration. Thanks for the response.
if let user = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "parseJSON") as? [String:Any],
           let userToken = user["token"] as? String {

```
       let url = URL(string: "http://fmm.dummy.com/api/v1/auth/me")!
       var request = URLRequest(url: url)

       let tokenString = "Bearer " + userToken
       request.setValue(tokenString, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
       request.httpMethod = "POST"

       //launch session
       URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in

           //check if no error
           if error == nil{

               do {

                   let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary

                   guard let parseJSON = json else{

                       print ("Error While Parsing")
                       return
                   }
                   print(parseJSON)

                   let statusMsg = parseJSON["status"] as? String

                   if  statusMsg == "OK"{
                       //token still valid
                       self.login()

                   }else {
                       //token is invalid
                       // get main queue to communicate back to user
                       DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                           let message = parseJSON["status_msg"] as! String
                           appDelegate.infoView(message: message, color: colorSmoothRed)
                       })
                   }



               }catch{
                   // get main queue to communicate back to user
                   DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                       let message = "\(error)"
                       appDelegate.infoView(message: message, color: colorSmoothRed)
                   })
                   return

               }


           }else{

               // get main queue to communicate back to user
               DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                   let message = error!.localizedDescription
                   appDelegate.infoView(message: message, color: colorSmoothRed)
               })
               return
           }
           }.resume()



   }
```

I'm trying to write code in appdelegate.swift that checks if the token saved from a previous login is still valid or has expired! the saved object on the user device is as follows. When i print user to the console i get this. ::--

Optional({
    response =     {
        token = "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjIsImlzcyI6Imh0dHA6XC9cL3htbS54bW9iaWxlbW9uZXkuY29tXC9hcGlcL3YxXC9hdXRoIiwiaWF0IjoxNDk2ODUyNTkxLCJleHAiOjE0OTY4NTYxOTEsIm5iZiI6MTQ5Njg1MjU5MSwianRpIjoiOTFhYjE0MjZkMGZmN2RjZDVjOTQzNTlkZGY4OGY0ZmYifQ.WaQFprfRbJMDQ72IORtWrcSmUqY3EaJp5BAqjijvUAc";
        verified = 1;
    };
    status = OK;
})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using too many optionals which can cause unexpected literal `"Optional(<value>)"` when calling the `description` method.

Unwrap all optionals safely with optional bindings:

```
if let user = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "parseJSON") as? [String:Any],
    let userToken = user["token"] as? String {

    let url = URL(string: "http://fmm.dummy.com/api/v1/auth/me")!
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)

    let tokenString = "Bearer " + userToken
    request.setValue(tokenString, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    ...
```

As always, **never** use `valueForKey` to get a single object from `UserDefaults`, use always `objectForKey`, and **never** use `NSDictionary` for a property list compliant dictionary, use always `[String:Any]`.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer, please check my edit.
Thank you very much

Comment: What is the continuative question? And please. I wrote *never use NSDictionary for a property list compliant dictionary*. JSON objects are property list compliant

Comment: Above code is doing absolutely nothing, not even errors are displaying. Sorry if i'm being naive and utterly useless but i'm a 3 week old swifty! 
i believe  am not retrieving the token from the saved object correctly.

Comment: No errors are displayed because the code received the data properly. In the `statusMsg == "OK"` scope you have to write `if let response = parseJSON["response"] as? [String:Any], let verified = response["verified"] as? Bool, verified == true  { print(response["token"] as! String) }`. That prints the token if it's verified.             `